# Efficiency of Indexed Placeholders

Tags: c#, performance

There are several places where you can use the indexed placeholder syntax in C#, ie.

```
// Assume some object is available with 2 string properties
Console.Writeline("Hello {0}, today is {1}", obj.Username, obj.DayOfWeek);
```

Is that more efficient than using the string concatenation operator to build the string? ie.

```
Console.Writeline("Hello " + obj.Username + " today is " + obj.DayOfWeek);
```

Obviously the `{0} ... {n}` syntax is cleaner if you're doing something complicated -- but which code is more efficient (lower memory footprint and or execution time?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first version has to parse the string and interpret it, before doing the actual string concatenation.  So one would expect the first method to be slower, and potentially more memory-intensive, no?

But unless you're doing vast amounts of string processing, it's unlikely to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think about it, use the formatting one. If you worry about memory/execution time with such a method, you have other problems.

Comment: I realize that it's stupid to worry about it in the context of a single line of code, but what if you needed to do some string operations on millions of strings?

Comment: In that case, use a `StringBuilder`.